# PHP/MySQL/PDO - Login form not recognising existing users

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, passwords, encryption

My login form isn't recognising existing users. The passwords I have stored in the database are encrypted using PHP's crypt() function. When the user registers their password is also encrypted and inserted into the database.

As you can see in the code below it checks to see if the password entered below matches, but whenever I enter in a password that is stored in the database with the corresponding username it says that the user does not exist.

I'm new to PDO and this is my first time using it, normally if I just use MySQL it works fine, but for some reason this isn't, I have changed the code a bit yet it still does not work. Anyone know why/where/what I'm doing wrong with the code.

```
include "connect.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($statement->execute())
{
    if($statement->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(crypt($password, $row['username']) == $row['user_password'])
        {
            $username = $row['username'];
            $email = $row['email'];

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            include "error_login.php";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        include "error_login.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: Both your if statements includ `error_login` if they're false - do you know which one is being called?

Comment: use `session_start();` on top also

Comment: @andrew: but only if the crypt doesn't match.

Comment: @andythebrit: go shotgun. add some debug `echo` statements throughout, so you can figure out what code path is being taken. Most likely the code itself is fine, but your crypts in the DB aren't what PHP is producing so no password will ever match.

Comment: You need to use `session_start()` at the top or all of those session variables won't be able to be accessed. Also, it might be helpful to note that if you use `crypt()` twice on the same string without specifying a 'salt' string, it will output two different results because `crypt()` will automatically generate a salt.

Comment: look at using openwalls PHPass for better security

Answer (score 0):

```
if(crypt($password, $row['username']) == $row['user_password'])
```

Should be

```
if(crypt($password) == $row['user_password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify a password with its stored hash-value, you need to know the salt and the algorithm that was used to generate the hash-value before. This salt can be extracted from the stored hash-value, because crypt() stores it as part of the resulting string.

```
if (crypt($password, $row['user_password']) === $row['user_password'])
```

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and password_verify() ready, to simplify generating BCrypt hashes. I strongly recommend to use this excellent api, or it's [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. The usage is very straightforward:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```